# Cocoa/OSX console messages: Could not setup Mach task special port 9: (os/kern) no access

Tags: python, macos, console, cron

I have a data gathering app (terrestrial magnetic field strength) that has four phases; they run, via cron, at 2,3,4, and 5 minute intervals, ordered so that everything needed for one step is collected before it happens.

Because of the intervals, I can't, as I understand it, use launchd to fire the phases; consequently, I use cron. And I *want* to use cron; I like it, it's convenient, familiar, etc.

But cron, under 10.5.8 Leopard (required -- driver issues preclude 10.6), vomits the subject message with *every* launch, basically littering what would be a useful window with useless trash. In the crontab, I'm setting the PATH, SHELL and HOME variables; the apps, which are written in python, all run properly and with the expected R/W access to the equipment, directories and files they need to get at; they launch other python subtasks fine; yet, there's the complaint from cron at launch, as if something is wrong.

Perhaps something is. But googling, I basically found four things:

1) This problem has existed for a loooong time -- Apple has not addressed it

2) If something's actually wrong with a typical cron launch, no one seems to know what it is

3) This is really common, and the usual suggestion is "launchd", which won't work

4) The only suggestion even close to a solution is to set /etc/syslog.conf logging level for the console to *err* instead of *notice*; but then one loses many benefits of the console in that case, and I'm very reluctant to run that way.

What I"m hoping is that here on stackoverflow, there will be someone who actually knows specifically what the error message means (as opposed to "launchd is unhappy / busted") or has even quietly solved the problem on their own.

Also, if I figure this out -- I've spent an unconscionable number of hours on it already -- I'll post here and so others can finally find a solution.

Comment: Not that this helps you, but you can indeed use launchd for such scheduled tasks. As you say, Google is replete with such resources.

Comment: Really? I had read in several places that you couldn't control launches at a granularity of minutes... is that not so?

Comment: Not so. Indeed on mac OS x, crontab is managed by launchd, so it _must_ be at least as flexible as launchd.

Comment: Graham, thanks for that. I went and read up on launchd; and while I agree it looks like it could launch my three tasks at the appropriate intervals, it also looks to me like in order to do it, it will require three extremely wordy .plists and a working knowledge of XML to do the same job that cron does with three short, elegant lines of text. have I missed something, or are they really trying to replace a line in cron with what amounts to paragraphs of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I've done a LOT of googling, and there are several things of note about this issue. First, the problem has existed for years. There are huge numbers of complaints about it on the net. I found a post in the Apple dev forums where it was said that Apple knew about it, it's a bug, and would be fixed at some future point. Of course, that remark was posted years ago (three, in fact), and apparently, Apple *isn't* going to fix it. And in the meantime, I have these bloody console messages which are seriously inconveniencing me. I have real work to do and I need to use the console output in that work.

So I fixed it. :) Yes, my cron jobs are now running quietly and correctly, the way they always should have.

Now, I would like to emphasize that this is a brutal fix, and a hack, but it is fairly specific to the problem, I don't think it can hurt anything else (if performed correctly), and serves MY needs perfectly. Your mileage may differ, and if you're not a technical person, stop reading now and just forget your ever saw this post. Really. Stop now.

So basically, as you can see in the above posting of the relevant chunk of source code from launchd that Graham dug up, there's a function call that reports this particular error. And pretty much just this particular error.

It has four parameters, one of which is returned from a call to mach_error_string(). The only parameter that is a pointer (meaning, the called routine could somehow get back to the original parameter) is the string pointer, and self-modification of a static format string... nah. That's not the kind of thing serious Koolaid drinkers would ever do. So the call isn't doing anything to those parameters; its just using them to report the error. So clearly, we don't need to make this call. Ah-ha. :)

This call to mach_error_string turns out to be a unique signature in the 10.5.8 version of launchd. That allowed me to precisely locate the code within the launchd executable. Once there, it was pretty obvious (to me, anyway) what is going on; there are the appropriate number of move instructions, then the call, then the loop is checked and either exited or re-run. Here's the relevant portion of the disassembly:

```
+193    0000fcd9  e87e050100              calll       0x0002025c                    _mach_error_string
+198    0000fcde  89442410                movl        %eax,0x10(%esp)
+202    0000fce2  8b462c                  movl        0x2c(%esi),%eax
+205    0000fce5  c7442408b8b90100        movl        $0x0001b9b8,0x08(%esp)
+213    0000fced  895c2404                movl        %ebx,0x04(%esp)
+217    0000fcf1  893c24                  movl        %edi,(%esp)
+220    0000fcf4  c1e808                  shrl        $0x08,%eax
+223    0000fcf7  25ff030000              andl        $0x000003ff,%eax
+228    0000fcfc  8944240c                movl        %eax,0x0c(%esp)
+232    0000fd00  e857afffff              calll       0x0000ac5c
```

The binary signature of the call (again, I emphasize, in the 10.5.8 version of launchd on my machine) is: E857AFFFFF. There's only one instance of this binary string in the entire file.

What we need to do here is replace that with something harmless (in context) of the same length. nearby, there's an immediate AND instruction for eax; that'll do. The value in eax isn't used again as the loop ends after the call. The binary for that AND instruction is: 25FF030000. Even if, worst case, at load time, the code were relinked so that (what was) the calll address was changed, all that would happen is the and instruction would have a different AND pattern. So no matter what, this should be ok to do.

So we replace the E857AFFFFF with 25FF030000, and now what the code does is load up those parameters, AND the eax register to no point at all, and go on with life. no more "Could not setup Mach task special port %u: %s" messages. Ever. And launchd will continue to work just like it always did, because all that has been done here is to excise a call to log an error message.

Now... just a couple closing remarks.

First, although the hack is quite specific, it isn't what I'd call surgically precise; it is possible that there might be lurking somewhere a situation that would legitimately call for this message, or a message emitted using this format string and parameters with a different port number and/or string at the end; and that's not going to be logged if it happens. So be aware of that. Error handling, such as it is, won't change, but the logging... that's now impossible.

Second, this is hacking in the classic sense; for me, it was both fun and very satisfying, serving the purpose of raising my central digit in Apple's general direction for inconveniencing me with something they could have *easily* fixed themselves; for you, though, if you're not comfortable with machine code and binary, and/or not very certain you can do this exactly right... and you're not completely prepared to have to firewire into your machine and replace the hacked launchd with the original again... or you don't have 10.5.8... don't even try it. Just write Apple and tell 'em to fix their broken launchd.

So... Apple gives us a bug; drops the ball on fixing it; I entirely lost patience and hacked it out of my face. And there you have it. Pbbffft.

Comment: I replaced E857AFFFFF with 25FF030000 in launchd on my PPC OS X 10.5.8 and rebooted but I still get the following every time cron runs: 03/03/2014 22:44:00 com.apple.launchd[1] (0x113dc0.cron[298]) Could not setup Mach task special port 9: (os/kern) no access

Comment: This mod changes the Intel code. It won't help a PPC system, sorry.

Comment: OK - thanks - that explains it - I wonder what the PPC fix is - the code looks the same - have you tried the later Snow Leopard cron on Leopard?

Comment: yes, it'd be the same process, just need a PPC disassembly, and hope for something as unique to pop its head up. No, I've not tried anything like that, I'm on Intel Snow Leopard now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the source :). Searching for your error message in http://www.opensource.apple.com/ finds this in [launchd_core_logic.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-258.18/launchd/src/launchd_core_logic.c):

```
kern_return_t
job_mig_post_fork_ping(job_t j, task_t child_task)
{
    struct machservice *ms;

    if (!launchd_assumes(j != NULL)) {
        return BOOTSTRAP_NO_MEMORY;
    }

    job_log(j, LOG_DEBUG, "Post fork ping.");

    job_setup_exception_port(j, child_task);

    SLIST_FOREACH(ms, &special_ports, special_port_sle) {
        if (j->per_user && (ms->special_port_num != TASK_ACCESS_PORT)) {
            /* The TASK_ACCESS_PORT funny business is to workaround 5325399. */
            continue;
        }

        errno = task_set_special_port(child_task, ms->special_port_num, ms->port);

        if (errno) {
            int desired_log_level = LOG_ERR;

            if (j->anonymous) {
                /* 5338127 */

                desired_log_level = LOG_WARNING;

                if (ms->special_port_num == TASK_SEATBELT_PORT) {
                    desired_log_level = LOG_DEBUG;
                }
            }

            job_log(j, desired_log_level, "Could not setup Mach task special port %u: %s", ms->special_port_num, mach_error_string(errno));
        }
    }

    job_assumes(j, launchd_mport_deallocate(child_task) == KERN_SUCCESS);

    return 0;
}
```

OK, so from here you should be able to find the name of the special port number 9, and therefore what launchd is trying to do when it posts the message. It looks like it's during the business of transferring mach ports from launchd to the child process, but I don't know what it's doing there. You may want to email `devbugs@apple.com` and ask them what radars 5325399 and 5338127 are, as these seem relevant to the implementation of that function.

Comment: in task_special_ports.h: #define TASK_ACCESS_PORT 9 /* Permission check for task_for_pid. */ unclear what this means, however, without context. Appears the task is being set up either asked for something, or is tested for something, and not getting it or failing the test, near as I can tell -- but what it is asking for is of course the key here, and I don't see how to tell. I can't find the actual function or macro, either -- just that header. I did find a description, also clear as mud, here: (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/osfmk/man/task_set_special_port.html)

Comment: Is your application signed? Only signed code is allowed to call task_for_pid().

Comment: Graham, I don't know what a "signed" application is. And I'm not calling task_for_pid. launchd is.  Secondly, my application is a series of python scripts, launched in the usual crontab fashion, nothing special about them at all, really -- and they work fine, the process is solid as a rock, been using it for almost a year now. This anomalous and vague error message just wrecks the usefulness of the console log output window, which is presently very much causing me trouble.